# Why is “Successfully” installed vsix Template for Visual Studio 2012 (appears in extension and update ) not appearing in Project Template

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2012, project, invisible

Why is “Successfully” installed vsix Template for Visual Studio 2012 (appears in extension and update ) not appearing in Project Template.
I can see only in tool menu (extension and update ) and cannot see any where else..
So no use for me as I cannot use the new template...

Log file below

```
20/06/2013 12:44:02 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
20/06/2013 12:44:02 - -------------------------------------------
20/06/2013 12:44:02 - Initializing Install...
20/06/2013 12:44:02 - Extension Details...
20/06/2013 12:44:02 -   Identifier      : VSIXProject8.Microsoft.4b7ebf96-1706-45f7-81a9-
7599e03b57fd
20/06/2013 12:44:02 -   Name            : VSIXProject8
20/06/2013 12:44:02 -   Author          : Microsoft
20/06/2013 12:44:02 -   Version         : 1.0
20/06/2013 12:44:02 -   Description     : custom project template
20/06/2013 12:44:02 -   Locale          : en-US
20/06/2013 12:44:02 -   MoreInfoURL     : 
20/06/2013 12:44:02 -   InstalledByMSI  : False
20/06/2013 12:44:02 -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : 4.5
20/06/2013 12:44:02 - 
20/06/2013 12:44:02 -   Supported Products : 
20/06/2013 12:44:02 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
20/06/2013 12:44:02 -           Version : 11.0
20/06/2013 12:44:02 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.VWDExpress
20/06/2013 12:44:02 -           Version : [11.0,12.0)
20/06/2013 12:44:02 - 
20/06/2013 12:44:02 -   References      : 
20/06/2013 12:44:02 - 
20/06/2013 12:44:02 - Searching for applicable products...
20/06/2013 12:44:02 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional
20/06/2013 12:44:02 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012
20/06/2013 12:44:03 - The extension with ID 'VSIXProject8.Microsoft.4b7ebf96-1706-45f7-81a9-
7599e03b57fd' is not installed to Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012.
20/06/2013 12:44:03 - Found installed product - Microsoft LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2012
20/06/2013 12:44:03 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Shell (Integrated)
20/06/2013 12:44:03 - Found installed product - Global Location
20/06/2013 12:44:11 - The following target products have been selected...
20/06/2013 12:44:11 -   Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012
20/06/2013 12:44:11 - 
20/06/2013 12:44:11 - Beginning to install extension to Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012...
20/06/2013 12:44:12 - Install to Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012 completed successfully. 
The extension has been installed to C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\\COMMON7
\IDE\EXTENSIONS\M3QOTQPH.Q5E\
```

Comment: finally link below helped me

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885241.aspx

 

now atleast i am getting under "New--Projects--Visual C#"

 

it will be helpful someone guide me how to get in Project template

Answer (score 1):

I fix this by Installing [ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 update](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=282650),

Click on the link install this update and then reopen Visual Studio 2012 Again, It will resolve your issue